# Factorization through diagonal morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

The following question came up when reading Hartshorne's proof of the valuative criterion.

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a $Y$-scheme and let $K$ be a field. Let $g\colon \operatorname{Spec}K\to X \times_Y X$ be a morphism with image in the diagonal $\Delta(X)$. Why is it true that $g$ factors through the diagonal morphism?

Is there a more general result giving a sufficient, purely topological (or even only set-theoretic) condition for a morphism to factor through the diagonal morphism?

Any kind of help and information is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the case when everything is affine?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for your comment. Yes, I was able to prove it in the affine case and I have got the full proof now(?): The generic point of $\operatorname{Spec}K$ is mapped into $\Delta(\operatorname{Spec}A)\subset \operatorname{Spec}(A \otimes_B A)$ for suitable rings $A$, $B$. From the affine case this gives a factorization through $\operatorname{Spec}A\to \operatorname{Spec}(A \otimes_B A)$ which yields the desired factorization through the original diagonal map after composing with the open immersion $\operatorname{Spec}A\to X$ and $ \operatorname{Spec}(A \otimes_B A) \to X\times_Y X$.